# Facing error while creating the a table with foreign key reference with on delete & update cascade

Tags: mysql

```
create table attendance2
(
  at2_id int not null identity primary key,
  at2_date date not null,
  at2_studentID int not null foreign key references students(s_id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
  at2_status varchar(20),
  at2_batchID int not null foreign key references batches(ba_id) on delete cascade on update cascade
)
```

*Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__attendanc__at2_b__3EE740E8' on table 'attendance2' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
*